# How to solve a system of $2$ linear equations modulo n for $3$ variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

$$2x + 2y - z = 2\pmod {3}$$

$$-x - 4y - 2z= 4\pmod {3}$$
I am lost in this... For simple equations I used Euclidean Algorithm. But in this problem I dont really know how to use this algorithm...

Comment: A general strategy for solving linear Diophantine systems is to compute the Smith normal form of the system. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: Exactly the way you solve it over rationals.

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $2$ and subtract it from the second.